# Swift Closure parameters, manipulate by position

Tags: ios, swift

How to manipulate the closure parameters by their position in Swift.
I've tried in the following way, But, couldn't get the idea behind it, from the [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

```
var additionClosure = {  (a : Int , b : Int )-> Int in
      return ($0 + $1)
}
var a = 10
var b = 20
println("additionClosure \(additionClosure(a,b))")
```

Any help would be appreciated..... Well, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you didnt understand?  $0--> 1st arg, $1--> 2nd arg like it follows

Comment: From the above snippet, how can a get addition of first & second parameters addition get printed. Right now the above snippet doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The numbered argument format is used for when you don't want to create a named closure.

Example:

```
import Foundation

func add(a : Int, b : Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func test(a : (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    println("result: \(a(10,20))")
}

test(add) // Calling test with a named closure

test({$0 + $1}) // Calling test with an anonymous closure
```

In the first case you define `add` with two parameters, and give them names `a` and `b`. In the second case, you don't even define the name of the closure, just the required functionality using `$0` and `$1`